# Extracting data in separate sheet excel using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-redshift

I want to write a python script from which I can execute multiple sql queries and the output of that query is saved in excel.
Suppose I have 4 sql query i.e Script1, Script2, Script3 & Script4 and I want to save the generated excel workbook in E:\Test, In that workbook sheet1 contains Script1 output, sheet2 contains Script2 output, sheet3 contains Script3 output, and so on. I have written a query but its working for only one script.
By using this script I am able to generate excel sheet with Test name, but How I run the remaining script so that their output will show in other sheet of same workbook
Please Help

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import pprint
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl.cell

COMMASPACE = ', '
def main():
    conn_string = "dbname='abc' user='qwerty' host='pqr' password='******' port='1234'"

    script1 = """
select * From something1    
"""
script2 = """
select * From something2    
"""
script3 = """
    select * From something3    
    """
script4 = """
    select * From something4    
    """
    pprint.pprint ('Making connection to the Database...')    
    con1 = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cur = con1.cursor()
    pprint.pprint ('Execution Start')
    cur.execute(script) 
    if not cur.rowcount:
        pprint.pprint ('Oops! Error Occured')
    else:
        columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
        data = cur.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=columns)
        df.columns = map(str.upper, df.columns)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('E:\\Test.xlsx')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        def hide_column(ws, column_id):
            if isinstance(column_id, int):
                assert column_id >= 1, "Column numbers must be 1 or greater"
                column_id = openpyxl.cell.get_column_letter(column_id)
            column_dimension = ws.column_dimensions[column_id]
            column_dimension.hidden = True
        writer.save()
    print ("END of extraction")    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using pandas `read_sql` with Sql Alchemy.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

# Parameters for SQL Alchemy
ServerName = "your_Server_Name"
Database = "Your_Database"
Driver = "Your_Driver"

# Create the connection
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + ServerName + '/' + Database + "?" + Driver)

# reading in the dataframes
df1 = pd.read_sql_query("select * from somewhere", engine)
df2 = pd.read_sql_query("select * from somewhere_else", engine)

# Using openpyxl to write to excel sheets
file = 'Your_file_path_Here'
book = load_workbook(file)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book

# now start writing them to sheets
df1.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name='SQL1')
df1.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name='SQL2')
```

Comment: Hi MattR, I am using Redshift database how I connect without user and password?
I am unable to establish connection.

Comment: @AquilAbbas, check out [this module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlalchemy-redshift). Admittedly, I've never used redshift before. But if the code is too hard to crack, You could also just create CSV files within redshift and read them that way within pandas.

Comment: or [look here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/install-odbc-driver-windows.html) to download the driver for this to work. Or skip SQL Alchemy and check [this link](https://blog.blendo.co/access-your-data-in-amazon-redshift-and-postgresql-with-python-and-r/).